# How to compress a VERY large binary sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, compression, sparse-matrix

We are talking about matrix size 2M * 500K with about 1% of elements being `True`. If stored using `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, the size is about 90GB.

The matrix will not be modified once constructed. It will only be read by rows.
Any ideas folks?

Since `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` uses three arrays(`data`, `indptr`, `indices`) to represent the binary spare matrix. In my own data structure, I can simply remove the `data` array since I know all elements will have the value of 1. This reduces the size of the sparse matrix by half to 45GB. How can I further compress it?

Comment: If you only need it row-wise you don't need to hold it in memory. Shove it into an hdf5 file and read it as needed.

Comment: @CJR Thank you! That is a great idea, I've never used hdf5 before, do you have any link that shows how this can be done? Also, we will read it quite often, I will have to investigate into the IO overhead.

Comment: I don't think this is something which one should approach without a more clear idea of usage / access patterns. When iterating forward, delta-filtering  a-priori dict/entropy-coding on top of csr structure sounds promising. For random-access of rows however, delta-encoding can't be on row-indices and things will be more hard to be "with cheap overhead". For row-based random-access i don't see hdf helpful too.

Comment: @sascha I agree with your sentiment in general but you only need a single random-access per row with a CSR matrix. There will be some overhead but it's probably not going to be crippling, and rows can be read out as blocks if there's an iterative order. I don't know of any other easily-implemented alternatives.

Comment: @HuadongFeng http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/